# Facebook Events AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Trying to use AngularJS to display public Facebook events on a webpage.
Came across this on google:-
http://blog.austinkpickett.com/using-angularjs-to-pull-facebook-events/

Followed the instructions to the letter, however, I dont know if the article is out of date, but how do I get an "access token". I've registered as a developer and have the app ID and App Secret, but I cannot see anywhere where the access token is!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different Access Tokens, the official docs explain in detail how to generate them: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Basically, there are these Tokens:

- App Token (valid forever)
- User Token (valid for 2 hours)
- Extended User Token (valid für 60 days)
- Page Token (valid for 2 hours)
- Extended Page Token (valid forever)

Another tutorial: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/